# Имитировать нажатие клавиш клавиатуры на Python под Mac OS и Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, mac, клавиатура

Требуется сымитировать нажатие клавиш клавиатуры под Mac OS и Linux на Python. Как это сделать?
P.S. Встречал модуль win32, но соответственно он под Windows.

Comment: [Это](http://ubuntovod.ru/raznoe/autoenterpass.html) не помогает?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5714072/4827341

Comment: библиотека Sikuli посмотрите